# adding modifier to element without using @extend - CSS, BEM

Tags: css, sass, bem

I am trying to wrap my head around the correct approach of writing BEM modifier rules inside parent classes. I have been using SASS's `@extend` but feel like doing it this way is wrong. Here is what I mean:

Say I have a `.form` class which looks like this:

```
<div className="form--inverse">

.form
  background-color: $white
  color: $black
  ...
  &__label
  ...
  &__input
  ...
```

I then want to add a modifier called `.color-inversed` which would look like this:

```
  &--color-inveresed 
    @extend .form // this is my question. Read on. 
    background-color: $black
    color: $white
```

and nest it inside the `.form` class:

```
.form
  &__label
  &__input
  &--color-inversed
  ...
```

should I really be `@extend`ing `.form` inside `--color-inversed`? It feels wrong to do so as the the final CSS will be bloated with repeating rules for all the elements extended via their modifiers.

Yet, if I don't extend it, `div class='form--color-inversed` will completely ignore all the `.form` rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use adding modifier to element with @extend, since in BEM modifiers are not standalone classes. You use the modifier in conjunction with it's modified class:

```
<div class="form form--color-inversed"></div>
```

> Modifier is an extra class name which you add to a block/element DOM
>   node. Add modifier classes only to blocks/elements they modify, and
>   keep the original class

[getbem.com naming docs](http://getbem.com/naming/)

Comment: ahhh. Now I get it. So, in my case the first `form` will inherit the element styling then `form--color-inversed` will pick up the `&--color-inversed` modifications. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Comment: `.form` is the block modifier, `.form__label` is an element (inside the block) modifier, and `.form--color-inversed` modifies the block, while `.form__label--active` modifies the element.